Mouseover event doesn't propagate as expected (Add Button effect)
I wanted to do a simple highlight on a button at the place where you hover over it, following the cursor.
If anyone knows a way to do this without js that would be even better (found one crazy post out there), but i tried to do it with a eventhandler for mouseover.
I am moving the nested div when hovering over the button, but on my site it doesn't propagate the event when hovering over the child and in this simple recreation it only works when hovering over the child.
Feeling like i am doing something really wrong here but can't see it.


var button = document.querySelector('.button');
var highlightDiv = document.querySelector('.highlight');

button.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    const x = (e.pageX - button.offsetLeft - 300 / 2) + 15;
    const y = (e.pageY - button.offsetTop - 100 / 2) + 15;
    highlightDiv.style.setProperty('--x', `${x}px`);
    highlightDiv.style.setProperty('--y', `${y}px`);
});
.button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 70px;
}

.highlight {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: radial-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
  transform: translate(var(--x), var(--y));
}
<button class="button">
  Button Text
  <div class="highlight"></div>  
</button>




I don't understand your description of what this is supposed to do. The colored square keeps jumping around as I move the cursor inside the Button Text box.

it is supposed to follow the cursor and does so on my website (until hovering over the element itself), but i can't find any difference to this simple example. my problem is with the propagation, the highlight in the example here does update to the curser position, when hovering over it, but not when over the parent

Sometimes the solution to issues like this is using mouseenter instead of mouseover (or vice versa), but I tried making that change to your snippet and it didn't seem to change anything.

Let's use a radial gradient, centered on the mouse position.


const button = document.querySelector('.button');

button.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  button.style.setProperty('--x', `${e.offsetX}px`);
  button.style.setProperty('--y', `${e.offsetY}px`);
});
.button:hover {
  background-image: radial-gradient(at var(--x) var(--y), #e66465, #9198e5);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 70px;
}
<button class="button">
  Button Text
  <div class="highlight"></div>  
</button>



Here's a nicer example. AI assisted.


const button = document.getElementById('radialButton');

button.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  button.style.setProperty('--x', `${e.offsetX}px`);
  button.style.setProperty('--y', `${e.offsetY}px`);
});
#radialButton {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #3984ff;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: background-image 0.3s;
}

#radialButton:hover {
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle at var(--x, 50%) var(--y, 50%),
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%
  ),
  linear-gradient(#3984ff, #3984ff);
}
<button id="radialButton">Hover me</button>




thank you, using mousemove rather than mouseover did the trick
